# What version of spark in latest Cloudera QuickStart VirtualBox?

Tags: apache-spark

I am thinking to install the quick start virtual box of [Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/), search on Cloudera [download page](http://www.cloudera.com/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-7.html), but unable to find the spark version in the latest Cloudera QuickStart virtual box, can any have knowledge of this, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QuickStart VM latest 5.7 has spark version 1.6.0 by default.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have installed cloudera QickStart VM. Is this not added in the office documentation of VM so that we can know before install of what version of spark, scala, hadoop are in VM.